# Why this question is deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, specific-question, deleted-questions, post-ban

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829725/how-many-possible-sets-we-can-get) I have posted a problem which was down voted and deleted without noting how much tough the problem is. Also my account is disabled from questioning in math.stack website. Can you enable it again?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359174/how-do-i-approach-p-1-p-2-p-3-are-primes-p-2-neq-p-3-4-p-1-p-2) one also a college entrance problem,came in India's most prestigious college entrance exam. Some people probably had expertise in "basic" math and down voted and mentioned it **off topic**. If this website is not for Undergrad or High school student then mention at the step of signing in. Give me a reason to make it off topic which lead to disabling me from asking any more questions.

Comment: The first question has been undeleted and reopened.

Comment: The second question, which has four answers, all with positive scores, has been closed and, an hour ago, deleted.

Comment: Source of the question is [part of the context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). You've mentioned here on meta that it is from a college entrance exam, but I do not see any information about origin of the question in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the main problems that sites like stackexchange suffer is users who post questions nobody cares about in order to receive an answer nobody cares about — e.g. because the site is being used to solve the problem that the user has an incomplete homework assignment but wants to submit a completed one.

If you are not one of these people but still have an issue that is problem-centric, then it's your job to distinguish your post from those other sorts of posts — e.g. things like

- explain why the problem is something you (and maybe even others) might care about
- explain what you might hope to learn about from a response to your post
- explain what aspects of the problem you find difficult
- if there are obvious avenues to start the problem that don't pan out or give partial information that is likely relevant to any answer, include it so readers understand the difficulty and don't repeat work you've already done

Even without the need to distinguish your post from others misusing the site, these are still features that can contribute to a well-written post.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot see the question you gave in the first link so my answer will be based on the second.

What you have posted is a question. Just a question. What you haven't done is **show your attempts.** We don't know whether you've tried anything.

This is not a 'do-my-homework-for-me' site. Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and hopefully you will understand why we consider such questions as 'off-topic'.

Regarding your second point, this site is for everyone. There are many MSE users that are still in high school and ask similar questions to yours, but why their questions are successful is that they have pointed out specifically where, in their attempts, they couldn't go on.

Please also see [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), and in particular the section about how you can get out of one. So what you can do now is try to improve your existing posts, and hope that good enough quality would lead to a reopening of them.

Comment: Well, can you enable me to post questions? I will try to follow those rules. The second question was asked when I was a new user to this site.

Comment: No. But as I have said, improve the questions that you have posted and hope for the best.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Just so you know your remarks about the second post also apply to the first one, here is its complete text when it was closed: "Title: How many possible sets we can get?. Body: In how many ways a power set of a set can be partitioned into two sets $S_1,S_2$ such that; $ \cup_{X\in S_1} X=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$ and minimum cardinality of a element of $S_1$ is $k>1$ e.g; $$S=\{1,2,3\},S_1 = \{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\},S_2=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\}\}$$for $k=2$. Find a general formula for number of partitions as a function of $n$ and $k$."

Comment: @TheSimpliFire If I edit it how it can be reopened as it is not possible to see the question given in my first link ?

Comment: I would concentrate on the question in the second link rather than worry about the deletion of the first.